# Multiple transfer on single transaction?

Tags: web3.py, bsc, pancakeswap, bscscan

Sorry for a newbie question, i currently trying web3.py for swapping in pancake

Here i found someone able to do sequenced transfer on a single tx
https://bscscan.com/tx/0xc0129dc6b9bc7f29ef14a3e6a358b9a5df11cac94fb917a1d8abd4041e20c6a6

But the input data cant be decoded so i cant identify what function he did use on the tx

Does someone know what technique like this called and how to do it in web3.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a single transaction.  This is a transaction going to a smart contract. The smart contract does the work and makes multiple trades. `web3.py` is  involved only to initiate the transaction, the trading logic is programming in Vyper or Solidity smart contract programming languages.

Comment: Thank you very much. It actually true that the tx says from the creator address to a contract address created by himself. So the address in web3 which initiate the whole sequence made by the function in the smart contract paid the whole gas right?

Comment: Please open another question if you have additional questions